# Mysql to csv Unix - UTF8 encoding issue

Tags: mysql, unix, csv, utf-8

I'm trying to export data from a mysql utf8 encoded table to a csv file on a unix box, I'm using the below query to do that :

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/values3.csv' 
CHARACTER SET  utf8 FIELDS 
TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
ESCAPED BY '\\' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM VW_CLEAN_DATA;
```

The issue is that non latin characters are not correctly encoded in the csv file, and I can't open them in excel.

Is there something I need to change in my unix configuration ?

**Edit:**
I've tried oppening the file in notepad++, emacs etc ... or even cat it on the unix box but still have the same issue.

FYI, I'm emailing the file using mutt after generating it, and the file in the mail has the same issue than on the box

> sudo echo "Subject of the mail" | mutt -a "/tmp/values3.csv" -s "Todays offer for publishing" -- my_email@gmail.com

**Edit2**
My sytem configuration :

> Os : debian-6.0.32bit
>
> Mysql version :  5.1.72-2

What I'm exactly doing:
Step 1 -> extract the data from the database to csv using the query above
Step 2 -> send the file to my computer (by mail, or by FTP - I tried both Binary and text mode)

I'm also trying to cat the file on the server, and also have encoding issues. Diging further I checked on my locale setting, and something might be wrong there :

> $ locale

```
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
...
```

I try to change that using

> export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

but the issue is still the same

I checked the file, looks to be UTF8

> $file -bi values.csv
>
> **text/x-c++; charset=utf-8`**

Thanks !

Comment: Are you sure you open the file as UTF-8 in Excel? It could be a Excel problem, rather than mysql problem.

Comment: Do you succeed to open your file in Notepad++ with no problem ? Excel doesn't like UTF8 by default...

Comment: @Michael when doing a cat in unix, I see encoding issues, oppening the file with notepad++/emacs or any other tool I have the same issue. But when querying the database the characters are fine

Comment: Do you have SSH connection encoding and MySQL connection encoding (`SET NAMES...`) properly? or is this maybe a double-encoding issue?

Comment: Can you show a byte-by-byte hex dump of one of the lines of the file that has the malformed UTF-8? Also, which version of MySQL are you running, and on which platform?

Comment: If you transfer the file with FTP protocol, it may assume text mode and break your encoding. What is the character set of table/schema/fields for the data that you're exporting?

Comment: @Michael the char set of the schema is utf8 - default collation, when I query the datdabase running mysql, the characters are well displayed, the issue happens only with the export

Comment: I've also checked the file collation :  `/tmp$ file -bi values.csv - text/x-c++; charset=utf-8`, this is utf8, wondering why it is not diaplyed properly on the server

Comment: Just because when you "*query the datdabase running mysql, the characters are well displayed*" does **not** mean that the data is correctly encoded within MySQL.  If it was inserted under the wrong connection character set, but that same erroneous character set is used on the connection during data retrieval, the data will be incorrectly encoded at rest but transcoded into the correct encoding during data retrieval.  I suggest that you `SELECT HEX(my_column) FROM VW_CLEAN_DATA WHERE ...` and manually inspect the at-rest encoding of some known string.